# Elements in two arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, compare, element

So, in C++ I have two arrays - arr1 and arr2 and I need to find the largest number in array arr1 but that is not in array arr2.
For example if arr1 = {3, 5, 6, 7} and arr2 = {2, 4, 7}, then largest number in arr1 that is not in arr2 is 6. 
Can anybody help?

```
 lar = arr1[0];  


 for (int i=0;i<m;i++)
 {
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
       if (arr2[j] != arr1[i] && lar>arr1[i])
       {
          lar = arr1[i];
       }
    }
 }

 if (lar)
    cout << "Largest number " << lar << endl;
 else 
    cout << "There is not such a number" << endl;
```

Comment: Have you tried something that you want to share with us?

Comment: I know it's not very good

Comment: Post that into the question rather than as a comment!

Answer (score 0):

If you start by sorting both arrays, you can then scan through both arrays at the same time, until you find the element you're looking for.

Try coding that up, and then post it into your question. Currently you are likely to have your question closed for not having shown us your own attempt at the problem.

Comment: @Chantola if there isn't already a Stack Overflow question on how to sort an array in C++, I'll run naked through Notre Dame.

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm**
Here is am considering size of `arr1[] and arr2[]` are n and m respectively;
Step 1 : Sort both the arrays.
Step 2 : Now set `max = arr1[n-1]`
Step 3 : Now iterate through `arr2[]`, check whether the `max` is present in it or not.

```
//After sorting 
int max;
bool flag = flase;
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    max = arr1[i];
    for(int j = m-1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if(max > arr2[j])
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
        else if(max == arr2[j])
            break;
     }
     if(flag) 
         break;
}
//max has the maximum element here.
```

Comment: This is less efficient than it needs to be. You don't need to loop through the second array each time: you can keep track of where you've got to. Essentially, you go once through both arrays, and at each stage you move backwards a step in one of the arrays depending on the two elements you're currently looking at.

Comment: @chiastic-security : I am totally agree with you. We can apply binary search on 2nd array. And every look up cost at most `O(log(m))` time.

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` followed by `std::set_difference` will give this answer quite directly.